# Edge-sql on ubuntu missing method

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, ubuntu, mono

I have installed and tested edge with mono on my Ubuntu machine and it passed all the tests. Unfortunately edge-sql is not working. I want to make a request to a SQL server database and I get the following error:

```
Missing method System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior) in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll, referenced in assembly /home/merca/login/oauth-server/node_modules/edge-sql/lib/edge-sql.dll
Method not found: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync'.

http.js:691
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home/merca/login/oauth-server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:62:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SqlCommand implementation in Mono currently doesn't have the `ExecuteReaderAsync` method.

Try using the synchronous `ExecuteReader` or the `Begin/EndExecuteReader` methods.